# How to change the order that taxonomies are displayed in wordpress post admin (Taxonomy not term)

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I run a wordpress site that is used by visitors to filter a collection of books. Currently I have over 15 taxonomies (format, completion status, setting, genre etc), but they were created as and when I needed them, which means the order is very chaotic. I need a way to sort the taxonomies in the admin panel, so that I'm not contantly scrolling up and down the page when I'm applying the terms to the books.

To reiterate, I'm looking for a way to re-order the taxonomies themselves, **not** the terms within the taxonomies.

If there is a plugin that can do this then great, if not, is there a way to do this by coding? I'd also be happy to have the taxonomies displayed seperately at the bottom of the admin screen like custom fields, with a way to re-order them.

I've looked at Taxonomy Order plugin, but this just looks like it rearranges the terms not the taxonomies.

I've looked in to the Taxopress settings which is how I create my taxonomies, I've also looked in to CPT UI, but can't find a solution.